# upgrading of Birt to 4.3.2 --->org.eclipse.birt.report.exception.ViewerException: Fatal error occurred when try to startup report engine

Tags: java, eclipse, birt

I am working with BIRT from 2 months,
while upgrading from Birt3.2.20 to Birt4.3.2 I have faced bellow exception from Tomcat 7

in my J2EE application, to upgrade from Birt3.2.20 to Birt4.3.2 I came to know just replacing the old jar files in "Plugins" folder of application with new jar files from

```
birt-runtime-4_3_2\ReportEngine\lib folder jar files.
```

After doing the same I have restarted my **Tomcat 7** which throws bellow error

```
INFO: Deploying web application archive D:\Suneel\apache-tomcat-7\webapps\CADBReports.war
May 07, 2014 4:30:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://www.eclipse.org/birt/taglibs/birt.tld is already defined
org.eclipse.birt.report.exception.ViewerException: Fatal error occurred when try to startup report engine.
        at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.setEngineContext(ReportEngineService.java:328)
        at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtViewerReportService.setContext(BirtViewerReportService.java:1022)
        at org.eclipse.birt.report.listener.ViewerServletContextListener.contextInitialized(ViewerServletContextListener.java:62)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5291)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1655)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I have just replaced old jar's with new jar's in Birt 4.3.2 runtime/lib --- is this enough to upgrade or anything else needed.

**I am using**

Eclipse,
Tomcat 7,
Jsp.

Pls help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the reports embedded in your application or do you have Birt installed in Tomcat and just call the urls from your application?

In order to update your BIRT Installation, follow this steps:

1.Close Eclipse.

2.In your Eclipse plugins directory, delete all directories that start with "org.eclipse.birt".

3.Install the new BIRT version.

4.Restart Eclipse with the -clean option: eclipse -clean

If you have BIRT installed in Tomcat, you need to undeploy it, then install the new version. Here is the [link](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/admin/t_installing_birt_reports_viewer_apache_tomcat.html) with the install steps.

Comment: it's working now. now I need one more help I want to restrict birt exporting to PDF format not to all  , for that I have deleted emitters related to those formats and working.  but along with pdf it is showing option for  XLSX and XLS_SPUDSOFT , I cant find these two fromats related jars how to restrict them.      Thanks in advance :)

Comment: please create a new question for that, so that it would be easier to find the answer for others looking to do the same

Comment: Ya, I have created now. :)