# Fatal error occurred when try to startup report engine

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, birt

I am using Birt4.9 and done viewer setup as per https://eclipse.github.io/birt-website/docs/integrating/integrating

I am facing bellow exception from Tomcat 8

org.eclipse.birt.report.exception.ViewerException: Fatal error occurred when try to startup report engine.
at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.setEngineContext(ReportEngineService.java:334)

I tried the solution mentioned in below log, but issue is not resolving.

[upgrading of Birt to 4.3.2 --->org.eclipse.birt.report.exception.ViewerException: Fatal error occurred when try to startup report engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23516624/upgrading-of-birt-to-4-3-2-org-eclipse-birt-report-exception-viewerexception)

It looks, in ReportEngineFactory, FactoryObject returning a null and raising ViewerException.

public synchronized void setEngineContext(ServletContext servletContext) throws BirtException {

```
  if (this.engine == null) {
     IPlatformContext platformContext = new PlatformServletContext(servletContext);
     this.config.setPlatformContext(platformContext);
     Platform.startup(this.config);
     IReportEngineFactory factory = (IReportEngineFactory)Platform.createFactoryObject("org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.ReportEngineFactory");
     if (factory == null) {
        throw new ViewerException("birt.viewer.reportServiceException.STARTUP_REPORTENGINE_ERROR");
     }
```

can any one help to resolve the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

BIRT 4.9 requires Java 11. Are you using an older Java version?

Comment: I am using amazon corretto JDK 11